# locating common elements in 2D arrays

Tags: matlab, iteration

I have two very long 2D lists called "first_data*" and "second_data", and I would like to locate the elements that are equal and place them in the list "final_data". I have a MWE here:

```
first_data  = [1 2; 3 4]';
second_data = [1 2; 9 4]';


final = [];
for i=1:length(first_data(:, 1))
    for j=1:length(second_data(:, 1))
        if(first_data(i, 2) == second_data(j, 2))
            final = [final first_data(i, 1)];
        end
    end
end
```

This gives me 2, as desired. This works, but it is very computationally intensive for very large data sets. Is there a more efficient way to write the above code?

Comment: Are you sure the example code works? You declare `final_data` and reference it as `final` in the `if` block. A sample input for the two arrays would be helpful as well in case the solution from my answer does not work correctly for you.

Comment: @harpun I have clarified my question and added a small example that works

Comment: There are three common elements in the arrays. Shouldn't the answer be [1, 2, 4] instead of [2]?

Comment: I want to compare all elements in the second dimension (:, 2) and get a list of their position. The values in the first dimension at these positions are what I am interested in. So in my example (2, 2) is common (4), so I want (2, 1) of "first_data" and "second_data"

Comment: The main reason your code is slow is that you don't preassign `final`.

Comment: Btw: what result would you expect if the second column of `second_data` was 4 in all rows?

Comment: @Jonas I am only interested in unique items, so if there is 4 in all rows, I only need a single "copy" of the corresponding value in first_data

Comment: @Jonas How can I pre-assign, when I don't know the size final_data will have? I would like to see an example of this, if you know one.

Comment: @niles_1710373: You can either make an array you know will be large enough, and then clip the unused rows, or you can assign to, say, 100 rows, and add another 100 rows each time you'd outgrow the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ismember` will allow you to do what you want.

```
%# identify the rows in first_data's second column
%# that occur in second_data's second column
goodIdx = ismember(first_data(:,2),second_data(:,2));

%# return the corresponding values of first_data's first column
final = first_data(goodIdx,1);
```

Comment: goodIdx has the form [0 0 ... 1 ... 0], but if I manually call final = first_data([0 1], 1) then I get an error. Why is that?

Comment: @niles_1710373: `goodIdx` is a logical vector. `final_data(logical([0 1]))` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
first_data  = [1 2; 3 4]';
second_data = [1 2; 9 4]';
diff_data=first_data-second_data;
Ind=find(diff_data==0);
final=first_data(Ind);
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
[c, ia, ib] = intersect(first_data(:, 2), second_data(:, 2));
final = second_data(ib,1);
```

note: I haven't tested this, but it should work (at least up to row/column mixups)

Answer (score 0):

So your two datasets can be completely described by the following tuples?

"first_data" described by `(i,j,data_1)` - which indicates that the value data_1 is at row i, column j

"second_data" described by `(i,j,data_2)`

And you want to find such tuples that are equal?

Convert "first_data", and "second_data" to **sets** using a [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Algorithm_description)

Perform *set intersection* using the Bloom Filter representation of "first_data" and "second_data" and obtain essentially constant time set intersection using the bitwise AND of the two representations.